# How to parse this json object correctly?

Tags: flutter

As a learner, I'm trying to build my first project, however I'm facing a problem trying to parse this json object

```
{
    "_id": 14080,
    "ankamaId": 14080,
    "name": "Amulette Séculaire",
    "level": 200,
    "type": "Amulette",
    "imgUrl": "https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus-touch/www/game/items/200/1230.png",
    "url": "https://www.dofus-touch.com/fr/mmorpg/encyclopedie/equipements/14080-amulette-seculaire",
    "description": "Finalement, le secteur de la bijouterie n'a pas tellement évolué ces cent dernières années.",
    "statistics": [
        {
            "Vitalité": {
                "min": 251,
                "max": 300
            }
        },
        {
            "Intelligence": {
                "min": 61,
                "max": 80
            }
        },
        {
            "Agilité": {
                "min": 16,
                "max": 25
            }
        },
        {
            "Sagesse": {
                "min": 31,
                "max": 40
            }
        },
        {
            "PA": {
                "min": 1,
                "max": null
            }
        },
        {
            "Prospection": {
                "min": 16,
                "max": 20
            }
        },
        {
            "Dommages Feu": {
                "min": 8,
                "max": 12
            }
        },
        {
            "Dommages Air": {
                "min": 8,
                "max": 12
            }
        },
        {
            "% Résistance Neutre": {
                "min": 6,
                "max": 8
            }
        },
        {
            "% Résistance Feu": {
                "min": 6,
                "max": 8
            }
        },
        {
            "Résistance Critiques": {
                "min": 11,
                "max": 15
        }
    }
  ],
}
```

Below is the way I'm parsing the object.

> **item_model.dart**

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Item {

  int id;
    int ankamaId;
    String name;
    int level;
    String type;
    String imgUrl;
    String url;
    String description;
    List<Map<String, Statistic>> statistics;

    Item({
        this.id,
        this.ankamaId,
        this.name,
        this.level,
        this.type,
        this.imgUrl,
        this.url,
        this.description,
        this.statistics,
    });

    factory Item.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> data) => _$ItemFromJson(data);
    Map<String,dynamic> toJson() => _$ItemToJson ( this);

}

@JsonSerializable()
class Statistic {
    int max;
    int min;
    
    Statistic({
        this.min,
        this.max,
    });

    factory Statistic.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> data) => _$StatisticFromJson(data);
    Map<String,dynamic> toJson() => _$StatisticToJson(this);

    
}
```

> **item_model.g.dart**

```
Item _$ItemFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Item(
    id: json['id'] as int,
    ankamaId: json['ankamaId'] as int,
    name: json['name'] as String,
    level: json['level'] as int,
    type: json['type'] as String,
    imgUrl: json['imgUrl'] as String,
    url: json['url'] as String,
    description: json['description'] as String,
    statistics: (json['statistics'] as List)
        ?.map((e) => (e as Map<String, dynamic>)?.map(
              (k, e) => MapEntry(
                  k,
                  e == null
                      ? null
                      : Statistic.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>)),
            ))
        ?.toList(),
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$ItemToJson(Item instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'id': instance.id,
      'ankamaId': instance.ankamaId,
      'name': instance.name,
      'level': instance.level,
      'type': instance.type,
      'imgUrl': instance.imgUrl,
      'url': instance.url,
      'description': instance.description,
      'statistics': instance.statistics
          ?.map((e) => e?.map((k, e) => MapEntry(k, e?.toJson())))
          ?.toList(),
    };

Statistic _$StatisticFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Statistic(
    min: json['min'] as int,
    max: json['max'] as int,
  );
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$StatisticToJson(Statistic instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'max': instance.max,
      'min': instance.min,
};
```

Basically, what I want to do is show in a listview the max, and the min attribute of each element of the statistics list.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the order of the model class, is same as that of the Api data. Also the data types used is compatible. Here errors can creep in. I don't see any other issues in the code

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
What do you mean with "the order of the model class", and "the data types used is compatible?

Comment: The data you are getting from the API will be in a certain order. Like first could be Id, then Name, after that Level etc.. So it would be better if your model class also follow the same order. Again suppose one of your data value is String, and you use Integer in its place, as data type, errors can occur.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [tool](https://app.quicktype.io/) which you just provide it with the JSON message and it will give you a class with all the variables and two function by which can parse the JSON message to the object or vice versa.

Steps:

1. insert a JSON message to the tool and give the class a name (don't forget to choose dart as the language)
2. create a new dart file and paste the class from the tool (let's assume the class name is Item)
3. Call `final item = itemFromJson(jsonString);` for parsing the JSON to the new object

Which then you can access the variables by via e.g. item.id

---

**Edit:**
so for your code, it will be:

### item_model.dart

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final item = itemFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Item itemFromJson(String str) => Item.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String itemToJson(Item data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Item {
    Item({
        this.id,
        this.ankamaId,
        this.name,
        this.level,
        this.type,
        this.imgUrl,
        this.url,
        this.description,
        this.statistics,
    });

    int id;
    int ankamaId;
    String name;
    int level;
    String type;
    String imgUrl;
    String url;
    String description;
    List<Map<String, Statistic>> statistics;

    factory Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Item(
        id: json["_id"],
        ankamaId: json["ankamaId"],
        name: json["name"],
        level: json["level"],
        type: json["type"],
        imgUrl: json["imgUrl"],
        url: json["url"],
        description: json["description"],
        statistics: List<Map<String, Statistic>>.from(json["statistics"].map((x) => Map.from(x).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, Statistic>(k, Statistic.fromJson(v))))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "_id": id,
        "ankamaId": ankamaId,
        "name": name,
        "level": level,
        "type": type,
        "imgUrl": imgUrl,
        "url": url,
        "description": description,
        "statistics": List<dynamic>.from(statistics.map((x) => Map.from(x).map((k, v) => MapEntry<String, dynamic>(k, v.toJson())))),
    };
}

class Statistic {
    Statistic({
        this.min,
        this.max,
    });

    int min;
    int max;

    factory Statistic.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Statistic(
        min: json["min"],
        max: json["max"] == null ? null : json["max"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "min": min,
        "max": max == null ? null : max,
    };
}
```

You can access the variables via:

```
void main(){
  String jsonString = "{\"_id\":14080,\"ankamaId\":14080,\"name\":\"Amulette S\u00e9culaire\",\"level\":200,\"type\":\"Amulette\",\"imgUrl\":\"https:\/\/s.ankama.com\/www\/static.ankama.com\/dofus-touch\/www\/game\/items\/200\/1230.png\",\"url\":\"https:\/\/www.dofus-touch.com\/fr\/mmorpg\/encyclopedie\/equipements\/14080-amulette-seculaire\",\"description\":\"Finalement, le secteur de la bijouterie n'a pas tellement \u00e9volu\u00e9 ces cent derni\u00e8res ann\u00e9es.\",\"statistics\":[{\"Vitalit\u00e9\":{\"min\":251,\"max\":300}},{\"Intelligence\":{\"min\":61,\"max\":80}},{\"Agilit\u00e9\":{\"min\":16,\"max\":25}},{\"Sagesse\":{\"min\":31,\"max\":40}},{\"PA\":{\"min\":1,\"max\":null}},{\"Prospection\":{\"min\":16,\"max\":20}},{\"Dommages Feu\":{\"min\":8,\"max\":12}},{\"Dommages Air\":{\"min\":8,\"max\":12}},{\"% R\u00e9sistance Neutre\":{\"min\":6,\"max\":8}},{\"% R\u00e9sistance Feu\":{\"min\":6,\"max\":8}},{\"R\u00e9sistance Critiques\":{\"min\":11,\"max\":15}}]}";

  final device = deviceFromJson(jsonString);
  print(device.id);
}
```

Comment: I've tried with the model generated by this tool, however I had no success, maybe what I'm doing wrong is the way I'm trying to access to those elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://app.quicktype.io/) site for get your model from json, just copy and past

Answer (score 0):

There's a brilliant tool (not the one that other ppl linked) that creates dart code for your JSON:
https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

It helped me a ton when working with different APIs.
The dart code in your case would be this:

```
class myJson {
  int iId;
  int ankamaId;
  String name;
  int level;
  String type;
  String imgUrl;
  String url;
  String description;
  List<Statistics> statistics;

  myJson(
      {this.iId,
      this.ankamaId,
      this.name,
      this.level,
      this.type,
      this.imgUrl,
      this.url,
      this.description,
      this.statistics});

  myJson.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    iId = json['_id'];
    ankamaId = json['ankamaId'];
    name = json['name'];
    level = json['level'];
    type = json['type'];
    imgUrl = json['imgUrl'];
    url = json['url'];
    description = json['description'];
    if (json['statistics'] != null) {
      statistics = new List<Statistics>();
      json['statistics'].forEach((v) {
        statistics.add(new Statistics.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['_id'] = this.iId;
    data['ankamaId'] = this.ankamaId;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['level'] = this.level;
    data['type'] = this.type;
    data['imgUrl'] = this.imgUrl;
    data['url'] = this.url;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    if (this.statistics != null) {
      data['statistics'] = this.statistics.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Statistics {
  Vitalit vitalit;
  Vitalit intelligence;
  Vitalit agilit;
  Vitalit sagesse;
  PA pA;
  Vitalit prospection;
  Vitalit dommagesFeu;
  Vitalit dommagesAir;
  Vitalit rSistanceNeutre;
  Vitalit rSistanceFeu;
  Vitalit rSistanceCritiques;

  Statistics(
      {this.vitalit,
      this.intelligence,
      this.agilit,
      this.sagesse,
      this.pA,
      this.prospection,
      this.dommagesFeu,
      this.dommagesAir,
      this.rSistanceNeutre,
      this.rSistanceFeu,
      this.rSistanceCritiques});

  Statistics.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    vitalit = json['Vitalité'] != null
        ? new Vitalit.fromJson(json['Vitalité'])
        : null;
    intelligence = json['Intelligence'] != null
        ? new Vitalit.fromJson(json['Intelligence'])
        : null;
    agilit =
        json['Agilité'] != null ? new Vitalit.fromJson(json['Agilité']) : null;
    sagesse =
        json['Sagesse'] != null ? new Vitalit.fromJson(json['Sagesse']) : null;
    pA = json['PA'] != null ? new PA.fromJson(json['PA']) : null;
    prospection = json['Prospection'] != null
        ? new Vitalit.fromJson(json['Prospection'])
        : null;
    dommagesFeu = json['Dommages Feu'] != null
        ? new Vitalit.fromJson(json['Dommages Feu'])
        : null;
    dommagesAir = json['Dommages Air'] != null
        ? new Vitalit.fromJson(json['Dommages Air'])
        : null;
    rSistanceNeutre = json['% Résistance Neutre'] != null
        ? new Vitalit.fromJson(json['% Résistance Neutre'])
        : null;
    rSistanceFeu = json['% Résistance Feu'] != null
        ? new Vitalit.fromJson(json['% Résistance Feu'])
        : null;
    rSistanceCritiques = json['Résistance Critiques'] != null
        ? new Vitalit.fromJson(json['Résistance Critiques'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.vitalit != null) {
      data['Vitalité'] = this.vitalit.toJson();
    }
    if (this.intelligence != null) {
      data['Intelligence'] = this.intelligence.toJson();
    }
    if (this.agilit != null) {
      data['Agilité'] = this.agilit.toJson();
    }
    if (this.sagesse != null) {
      data['Sagesse'] = this.sagesse.toJson();
    }
    if (this.pA != null) {
      data['PA'] = this.pA.toJson();
    }
    if (this.prospection != null) {
      data['Prospection'] = this.prospection.toJson();
    }
    if (this.dommagesFeu != null) {
      data['Dommages Feu'] = this.dommagesFeu.toJson();
    }
    if (this.dommagesAir != null) {
      data['Dommages Air'] = this.dommagesAir.toJson();
    }
    if (this.rSistanceNeutre != null) {
      data['% Résistance Neutre'] = this.rSistanceNeutre.toJson();
    }
    if (this.rSistanceFeu != null) {
      data['% Résistance Feu'] = this.rSistanceFeu.toJson();
    }
    if (this.rSistanceCritiques != null) {
      data['Résistance Critiques'] = this.rSistanceCritiques.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Vitalit {
  int min;
  int max;

  Vitalit({this.min, this.max});

  Vitalit.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    min = json['min'];
    max = json['max'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['min'] = this.min;
    data['max'] = this.max;
    return data;
  }
}

class PA {
  int min;
  Null max;

  PA({this.min, this.max});

  PA.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    min = json['min'];
    max = json['max'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['min'] = this.min;
    data['max'] = this.max;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried with the model generated by this tool, basically I tried something like myJson.statistics[0].vitalit.min but I got null. Also I wanted to avoid this tool because in some myJson objects the statistics will vary.